# Google AMP Cache: Multiple pages navigation

Tags: html, amp-html

I might have missed it, but I try to find information on how to use multiple pages on the google cache using AMP.

What I've tried:
My `index.html` shows up as amp'ed page, but clicking a link, I leave the cache to the regular page, even though the other pages validate by the amp validator.
Regular links (a-href) are in place.

A: Is it a actually not possible to have a navigation and stay within the google cache?

B: Do I need another approach?

Thanks for any help possible